# From where appeared these variables in my kubernetes container?

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, 12factor

I am deploying simple hello-world microservice that listens on port given by following variable:

```
PORT = os.environ.get("TEST_SERVICE_PORT", "").strip() or "50001"
```

I deployed it without configuring any variables on container, and expected it to serve on default 50001 port, but instead got error

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

When I logged into container and checked environment, I found out that evironment is filled with different variables (some of them belong to other services), and `TEST_SERVICE_PORT` variable exists and contains definitely not port:

```
root@test-service-697464787c-xpd6k:/opt/app/src# env | grep TEST
TEST_SERVICE_PORT_7002_TCP_ADDR=10.145.23.43
TEST_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT_GRPC_API=7002
TEST_SERVICE_PORT_7002_TCP_PORT=7002
TEST_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.145.23.43:7002
TEST_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=10.145.23.43
TEST_SERVICE_PORT_7002_TCP=tcp://10.145.23.43:7002
TEST_SERVICE_PORT_7002_TCP_PROTO=tcp
TEST_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=7002
```

I have following questions and were not able find answers to them in documentation:

What created this variables? Could I somehow isolate container from them? Or are they set intentionally by kubernetes, and serve some purpose I don't know about? How should I name my configuration variables to avoid naming collisions? Should I use that variables istead of using services names as hostnames?

There is [following documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-environment-variables/), but it only explains variable `TEST_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT` and `TEST_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST`. What `TEST_SERVICE_PORT` and others mean then? What adds `TEST_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT_GRPC_API`?

There is also Istio and Ambassador gateway installed on cluster that I'm using.

Comment: Please share you yaml deployment file as well. It would make it easier to figure out where things go wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What environment variables are created in kubernetes by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759205/what-environment-variables-are-created-in-kubernetes-by-default)

Comment: @Alberto thanks, but that answers only 25% of my first question. Should I name services differently? Or use different prefix for environment variables? Or redefine variable inside container config in deployment?

Comment: @Bunyk please share with us your deployment file.

Comment: @abielak shared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q: What created this variables?

**A**: [discovery-service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services) (more at the end)

> Q: Could I somehow isolate container from them?

**A**: If you want to disable that, you can set `enableServiceLinks: false` on your [PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#podspec-v1-core)

> Q: Or are they set intentionally by kubernetes, and serve some purpose I don't know about?

**A**: No, they are there just there to give options besides DNS and names, kubernetes does not use them

> Q: How should I name my configuration variables to avoid naming collisions?

**A**: Either you use `enableServiceLinks: false` or use a naming pattern that does not conflict with the pattern described on the docs, usually I prefer use `_SVC_PORT` when I need to do something like you

> Q: Should I use that variables istead of using services names as hostnames?

**A**: From docs: "You can (and almost always should) set up a DNS service for your Kubernetes cluster",

> Q: There is following documentation, but it only explains variable TEST_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT and TEST_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST. What TEST_SERVICE_PORT and others mean then? What adds TEST_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT_GRPC_API?

**A**: You have a named port called `grpc-api`, in that case it is using the named instead protocol + port number. Note: I could not find any references on the docs for that, so I had dig into [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/envvars/envvars.go#L53)

---

From docs [discovery-service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services)

> When a Pod is run on a Node, the kubelet adds a set of environment
>   variables for each active Service. ... simpler {SVCNAME}_SERVICE_HOST
>   and {SVCNAME}_SERVICE_PORT variables, where the Service name is
>   upper-cased and dashes are converted to underscores...
>
> For example,
>   the Service "redis-master" which exposes TCP port 6379 and has been
>   allocated cluster IP address 10.0.0.11, produces the following
>   environment variables:
>
> ```
> REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_PORT=6379 REDIS_MASTER_PORT=tcp://10.0.0.11:6379
> REDIS_MASTER_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://10.0.0.11:6379
> REDIS_MASTER_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO=tcp
> REDIS_MASTER_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT=6379
> REDIS_MASTER_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=10.0.0.11
> ```

From k8s api [PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#podspec-v1-core)/EnableServiceLinks:

> **EnableServiceLinks** indicates whether information about services should be injected into pod's environment variables, matching the syntax of Docker links. Optional: Defaults to true.

Answer (score 0):

These environment variables help with service discovery. You can disable them by setting

```
$ kubectl explain deployment.spec.template.spec.enableServiceLinks
KIND:     Deployment
VERSION:  extensions/v1beta1

FIELD:    enableServiceLinks <boolean>

DESCRIPTION:
     EnableServiceLinks indicates whether information about services should be
     injected into pod's environment variables, matching the syntax of Docker
     links. Optional: Defaults to true.
```